# Pros and cons of using Arrays.asList

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I would like to know the pros and cons of using `Arrays.asList`. I am facing an issue while using this in my code.

Also I would like to know the best way of converting an array to array list (collection) without using `Arrays.asList`

Comment: what is the issue that your facing.you must be trying to add some elements..this is not possible in Arrays.asList.Its just a list wrapper around an array.

Comment: @Emil good point, in which case `new ArrayList<> (Arrays.asList(array));` would do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convert an array to an ArrayList, I would do this :

```
new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(myArray));
```

You need to wrap your list in a new ArrayList, otherwise you will not be able to add any element, because the list returned by *asList()* has a fixed size. So you get an UnsupportedOperationException while trying to add elements.

But you may also want to do this, if you do not like the above method :

```
Collections.addAll(arraylist, array);
```

Both are equivalent performance-wise, **as far as I know**.

---

But more important, what is your problem with using the first method ?

Comment: I am getting UnsupportedOperationException. The scenarios is, I do not want the array to be repopulated.

Comment: The issue got resolved, a work around helped. I used a "for" loop for adding elements from array into the list.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to know the pros and cons of using Arrays.asList.

The main "pros" are:

- it doesn't involve copying the data,
- your list will see any changes made in the backing array (if you want that)

The main "cons" are:

- you cannot add or remove elements via the "asList" wrapper,
- your list will see any changes made to the backing array (if you don't want that)

(There is also an obvious limitation: you cannot apply `asList` to an array of primitives.  But converting an array of primitives is non-trivial anyway ...)

---

> I would like to know the best way of converting an array to array list (collection) without using Arrays.asList

The simplest way to turn an array into list without using aslist is:

```
new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(arrayOfT))
```

You may get slightly better performance with this:

```
ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(arrayOfT.length);
Collections.addAll(list, arrayOfT);
```

because the `ArrayList<T>(Collection<T>)` constructor starts by calling `toArray()` to create a temporary array (at least, in Java 7 it does).  This means that there is an extra copy going on under the hood.

But the bottom line is, just using `Arrays.asList` is *simpler and cheaper* than anything that avoids using it.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays.asList lets you look at an array as though it were a List. That means that future changes to the array will affect the List, and future changes to the List affect the array. Whether that is a good or a bad thing depends on what you intend to do with the List, and how you want it to relate to the array.

For throw-away use I would definitely go with Arrays.asList. For example, List has a toString that shows the content, so System.out.println(Arrays.asList(myArray)) can be useful.

If you want to keep a snapshot of the array, unaffected by future changes, I would still use Arrays.asList, but then create a new List from its result, as shown in the previous answer from @NNzz.

Comment: Long time no see! Welcome aboard!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the existing answers, specially a great answer by @Stephen C, there is one more problem with `Arrays.asList`.

From ***Effective Java***

---

`Arrays.asList` was never designed to gather multiple argument into a list, but it seemed good idea to retrofit it to do so when varargs were added to the platform. As a result, it become possible to do things like this:

```
List<String> homophones = Arrays.asList("to", ""too", "two");
```

This usage works, but it was a big mistake to enable it.

Prior to release 1.5, this was a common idiom to print content of an array:

```
// Obsolete idiom to print an array!
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(myArray));
```

The idiom was necessary because arrays inherit their `toString` implementation from Object, so calling `toString` directly on an array produces a useless string such as `[Ljava.lang.Integer;@3e25a5`. The idiom worked only on arrays of object reference types, but if you accidentally tried it on an array of primitives, the program wouldn’t compile. For example, this program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] digits = { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 4 };
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(digits));
}
```

would generate this error message in release 1.4:

> Va.java:6: asList(Object[]) in Arrays can't be applied to (int[])
>     System.out.println(Arrays.asList(digits));

Because of the unfortunate decision to retrofit [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) as a varargs method in release 1.5, this program now compiles without error or warning.

On the bright side, the [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) idiom for translating arrays to strings is now obsolete, and the current idiom is far more robust. Also in release 1.5, the [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class was given a full complement of [Arrays.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])) methods (not varargs methods!) designed specifically to translate arrays of any type into strings. If you use [Arrays.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])) in place of [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)), the program produces the intended result:

```
// The right way to print an array
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 8, I think the simplest and efficient way to create new Array is :

```
Stream.of(myArray).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Better no more use

```
new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList());
```

Since this is 2 times work, which impacting memory / performance degradation

About Arrays.asList, I think almost all people already explain clearly.
I want to add more just some bad experience for using Arrays.asList. This is already long time ago, so maybe irrelevant for some part on this point.

On one project some years ago I always use Arrays.asList because it is simpler and more clear list initialization. Then what I do is pass the arrayList on to another method and even libraries.
The problem is some library consider Arrays.ArrayList as a ArrayList. hence when it try to force casting into java.util.ArrayList it will cause a problem

```
List<String> arrayList = Arrays.asList(x);
ArrayList<String> arr = (ArrayList) arrayList; //this will cause error
```

- Some mapper (ex : dozer) cannot read the method signature of Arrays.asList earlier, so mapping will fail.
- I also found some case on some library it even throw UnsupportedOperationException when some method called, I don't know why.

Then we refactored all our code to remove Arrays.asList and not using it again.

So for one times use, example only for print, it's still acceptable, but better not use it to pass along value / for long time use.